# Indoor Location Using Beacons

Tags: ios, iphone, navigation, ibeacon, indoor-positioning-system

Hey I am implementing indoor location using beacons. I am done with indoor map and locating user location using beacon.
I am stuck at point where user want to search a path from its current location to destination. Currently I managed to implement it by providing the points of the whole path but that is not gonna be efficient in case of large areas.
eg. User is in room A and he want to search path for room Z. Currently I am using saving coordinates of the whole path. But I am looking for better solution if any.

I am not using MapKit I am simply using scroll view and pdf import.

This is how I am displaying path. 
Note: Path coordinates are stored in JSON file currently I put them manually.

```
UIBezierPath *path = [UIBezierPath bezierPath];
[path moveToPoint:CGPointMake(394.0, 290.0)];
[path addLineToPoint:CGPointMake(100.0, 290.0)];
[path addLineToPoint:CGPointMake(50.0, 250.0)];

CAShapeLayer *pathLayer = [CAShapeLayer layer];
pathLayer.frame = self.view.bounds;
pathLayer.path = path.CGPath;
pathLayer.strokeColor = [[UIColor redColor] CGColor];
pathLayer.fillColor = nil;
pathLayer.lineWidth = 2.0f;
pathLayer.lineJoin = kCALineJoinBevel;

[self.view.layer addSublayer:pathLayer];

CABasicAnimation *pathAnimation = [CABasicAnimation animationWithKeyPath:@"strokeEnd"];
pathAnimation.duration = 2.0;
pathAnimation.fromValue = [NSNumber numberWithFloat:0.0f];
pathAnimation.toValue = [NSNumber numberWithFloat:1.0f];
[pathLayer addAnimation:pathAnimation forKey:@"strokeEnd"];
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Got it. I am using graphs now. Its pretty simple now. Ill share my code later as well.

Comment: Are you still able to share this?